# Why am I getting an error about my ODBC driver when connecting python to sql script?

Tags: python, azure, odbc, driver, vscode-extensions

I wrote a python script that is retrieving data from APIs that are in a google sheet. Now I am trying to connect my python script to SQL so I can add the data to my tables. I am using jupyter notebook for python, and mssql and VS Code for my SQL script. When I try to connect the two I keep getting the same error about issues with not being able to open the Driver.

This is the code I have tried:

```
connection_string = "Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=xxxx;Uid=xxxx;Pwd={Password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30"

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)}")
```

And this is the error I keep getting this error even though I have downloaded ODBC Driver 18 on my mac:

```
Error: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)
```

Any recommendations on how to fix it?

Comment: was the drivers installed? can you check pyodbc.drivers() in your python code?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an open issue with pyodbc as can be seen on https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1116. I'd suggest you skim through the issues raised by users and follow the suggestions there to resolve this error.

Also take a look at PyPi to be sure you have pyodbc properly installed on your mac. According to [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/):
The easiest way to install pyodbc is to use `python -m pip install pyodbc`

> On Macs, you should probably install unixODBC first if you don't already have an ODBC driver manager installed. For example, using the [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager:

```
brew install unixodbc
python -m pip install pyodbc
```